# How to Pass TextView text from Recyclerview to other Activity in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I created a simple application which contain RecyclerView TextView and Images loaded from the Firebase.
Now I want to pass the text from TextView to other activity.
The TextView is in RecyclerView:
The code:

```
     FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new 
     FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
            Blog.class,
      R.layout.blog_row,
      BlogViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase
            ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, 
         Blog model, final int position) {
         final String post_keyy=getRef(position).getKey();
          viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setImag(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());

        }

     };
     mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

     public static class BlogViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
   {
   View mView;
    TextView post_title,post_desc;
    ImageView post_imge;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView=itemView;

    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.posttitle);
        post_title.setText(title);

    }
    public void setDesc(String desc)
    {
         post_desc=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
     }
      public void setImag(Context ctx,String image)
       {
         post_imge=(ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.postimg);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_imge);
       }


    }
```

Now I want to pass post_title textview text to other activity.

Comment: add on click event get textView text (or better text from coresponding item) inside the listener and use normal way to start new activity with parameters

Comment: public BlogViewHolder(View itemView,Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
            this.context=context;
        }  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(context,SubMenuu.class);
            i.putExtra("blog_id",post_title.getText().toString());
            context.startActivity(i);
        } but it give me error

Comment: Detail your error messages in your question.  It will help people provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add the onClickListener in the onBindViewHolder method of your RecyclerAdapter class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Set the OnClickListener on whatever view you want to trigger when clicked.
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //You can get the context from the view itself.
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), theOtherActivityName.class);
            //Put your intent extras.
            intent.putExtra("blog_id",post_title.getText().toString());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```